# Professor wants a Wireshark capture of mail client and browser activity of my own machine

Tags: email, wireshark

As part of a home exercise in my networking class, the professor is asking students to submit a Wireshark capture done on the students' private machines.

The capture must contain activity of the local mail client (e.g. refreshing mails) and arbitrary browser activity (browsing on a website of choice).

The capture should not be larger than 5000 packets or capture longer than one minute.

My device is a MacBook Pro, macOS 10.15, and the mail client would be Apple Mail.

I am worried that the capture may contain compromising data, especially from the mail client, but also other activity on my device which may be happening in the background. Are my worries justified?

Comment: Why not try it and analyze the results *before* you submit it to the professor?

Comment: You can also use filters to include only the information the instructor is looking for. Filtering for only port 443 (HTTPS) should capture everything (with a web mail client anyways) that the instructor is looking for, and it should all be encrypted. You might need some UDP ports if you want video traffic in the traffic dump.

Comment: Beware, auxilliary protocols like DNS could be interesting, depending on what is the goal of the exercise...

Comment: I would try to do these labs in class. I had same issues with 1 1/2 year old text-lab-book that created all kinds of issues. I bought cheap laptop to do wireshark labs, and any other labs that did not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Now days, that capture should be mostly encrypted traffic unless he's also expecting you to do a MiTM (Man in The Middle).

Check your capture before turning it in just in case of surprises.

You could also set up a disposable email account to use just for this assignment.

The most likely teaching moment is probably the potentially large amount of ancillary traffic from advertisers and third party web sites that take place under the covers of going to a commercial web page.

Comment: The professor possibly also wants to capture a few bad examples of people who are still using AUTH PLAIN in their mail clients.